# PDO update statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = " UPDATE users
        SET  name = ?, role = ?, status = ?
        WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = execute_query($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($name, $role, $status, $name));
if($stmt->rowCount()) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
```

```
    function execute_query($sql)
    {
        global $conn;
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        return $conn->prepare($sql);
    }
```

This throws the following, which means no row is affected. What mistake am I doing in the query?

```
(
[0] => 00000
[1] => 
[2] => 
)
```

Comment: Seems that you are updating a column with the same value .. $name , $name  .. is this what you need .. (and could be that $name don't match in where)

Comment: No PHP expert but you seem to execute the query before binding the variables: `execute_query($sql)`

Comment: Whatever it does, the function `execute_query($sql)` does not return a PDO object. How is this meant to work? Please take a look at a few explamples (you will find countless here on SO or on google or in the PDO documentation) and complare your code with the flow demonstrated there.

Comment: Maybe it didn't find any rows to match? If you can, try turning on sql logging (`set global general_log = 'on'`), run the query, turn the log back off, then check the log for the `Execute` line to see if the query is what you think it is, and then check if there really were any matches.

Comment: aynber - this is correct. Please post this as answer

Comment: Once a question is closed, it can't be answered.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. juergen thanks.